# If Statement in loop - Else, Else If

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I'm wondering if anyone could help with the below simple code:

```
For Each cell In Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastrow1, 5))
    If(cell.offset(, -3)=cell.offset(1,-3)) then cell.value = cell.offset(,-1),else if(cell.offset(, -3)=cell.offset(-1,-3),cell.value = 0,else     cell.valye = cell.offset(,-1))
Next
```

I'm basically trying to replicate the if statement giving me 3 different outcomes depending on wether the IF statement is true or not.

Comment: Does your code not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
    If (cell.offset(, -3) = cell.offset(1, -3)) Then
        cell.value = cell.offset(, -1)
    ElseIf (cell.offset(, -3) = cell.offset(-1, -3)) Then
            cell.value = 0
    Else
        cell.valye = cell.offset(, -1)
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not aware of the help availbale online regarding the syntax of commands you really should get familiar with it.

eg if [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx)

and generally [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sh9ywfdk.aspx)

```
For Each cell In Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(lastrow1, 5))

    If cell.Offset(, -3) = cell.Offset(1, -3) Then
            cell.Value = cell.Offset(, -1)

    ElseIf cell.Offset(, -3) = cell.Offset(-1, -3) Then

        cell.Value = 0

    Else

        cell.Value = cell.Offset(, -1)

    End If
Next
```